# asp.net mvc getting data from textbox on view back to stored procedure to edit record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET but have done 20 years of desktop dev. I have a `Customer` class with fields `CustId, CustName, CustNotes`.

I have a view called `CustView` that has some input boxes that are to be pre-populated with customer details from a previous view using the `CustID`.

I can show the customer details in the text boxes but I cannot get the user edited textboxes (ie the user changes the name of a customer) back to a stored procedure in an Action.

I use a DB class called `Cust1DBHandle` to call the stored procedure. I have set up 3 buttons and 3 actions in a bid to get any of them to work, either by passing variables or using `RequestString` but nothing works.

- **Question #1**: how can I pass the new text values back as either global variables, variables in the action or using a datamodel?
- **Question #2**: in the `CustViewDBHandle`, I populate a list of the results. Is that the correct thing to do if it’s only for one row of data?
- **Question #3**: when pressing a SAVE button that executes a stored procedure, do you have to have a return in the action in the controller?

Thanks.

Cust.cs model

```
public partial class Cust
{
    [DisplayName("Cust ID")]
    public Int32 CustID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Customer Name")]
    // [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string CustName { get; set; }
    
    [DisplayName("Customer Notes")]
    public string CustNotes { get; set; }

    public string ErrorMessageCust { get; set; }
}
```

`CustView.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<App22.Models.Cust>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CustView";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<header>
</header>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<title>CustViewy</title>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>
<p>

</p>
<p>CUSTOMER DETAILS ARE HERE</p>
<form name="1" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Headline Details</legend>
        <table>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="CustID">CustID:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="1CustID" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
item.CustID)" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="CustName">CustName:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="2CustName" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem 
 => item.CustName)" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="CustNotes">Cust Notes:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="3CustNotes" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
item.CustNotes)" />
                </td>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="action:Save1" value="Save" />

                        <button style="background-color:red" type="button" name="tree0" 
class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SaveCust0","Cust1")'">
                            SAVE0 &raquo;
                        </button>

                        <button style="background-color:blue" type="button" name="tree1" 
class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SaveCust1","Cust1",new { CustyIDSave = item.CustID , CustyNameSave = item.CustName })'">
                            SAVE1 &raquo;
                        </button>

                        <button style="background-color:green" type="button" name="tree2" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SaveCust2","Cust1")'">
                            SAVE2 &raquo;

                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`Cust1Controller.cs`:

```
public class Cust1Controller : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SaveCust0()
    {
        string message = "";
        
        message = Request.Form["CustName"].ToString();
        return Content(message);

        CustViewDBHandle dbhandle = new CustViewDBHandle();
        ModelState.Clear();
        dbhandle.SaveCust(Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["CustID"]), 
Request.Form["CustName"].ToString());
    }

    public ActionResult SaveCust1(int CustyIDSave, string CustyNameSave)
    {
        CustViewDBHandle dbhandle = new CustViewDBHandle();
        ModelState.Clear();
        dbhandle.SaveCust(CustyIDSave, CustyNameSave);
        return null;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveCust2(int CustyIDSave, string CustyNameSave)
    {
        CustViewDBHandle dbhandle = new CustViewDBHandle();
        ModelState.Clear();
        dbhandle.SaveCust(CustyIDSave, CustyNameSave);
        return null;
    }

    // GET: Cust1
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Cust1DBHandle dbhandle = new Cust1DBHandle();
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View("~/Views/Cust/Cust1.cshtml",dbhandle.GetCust(""));
        
       // return View("~/Views/Cust/Cust1.cshtml"); //This works
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Reload(string tree)
    {
        //tree = "Breaker2";
        Cust1DBHandle dbhandle = new Cust1DBHandle();
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View("~/Views/Cust/Cust1.cshtml", dbhandle.GetCust(tree));
        //Cust1DBHandle dbhandle = new Cust1DBHandle();
        //ModelState.Clear();
        //return View("~/Views/Cust/Cust1.cshtml", dbhandle.GetCust(SearchBy));

        // return View("~/Views/Cust/Cust1.cshtml"); //This works
    }

    public ActionResult ViewCust(int CustyIDView)
    {
        //tree = "Breaker2";
       
        CustViewDBHandle dbhandle = new CustViewDBHandle();
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View("~/Views/Cust/CustView.cshtml", dbhandle.GetCust(CustyIDView));
        //Cust1DBHandle dbhandle = new Cust1DBHandle();
        //ModelState.Clear();
        //return View("~/Views/Cust/Cust1.cshtml", dbhandle.GetCust(SearchBy));

        // return View("~/Views/Cust/Cust1.cshtml"); //This works
    }
}
```

`CustViewDBHandle.cs`:

```
public class CustViewDBHandle
{
    // ********** VIEW CUSTOMER DETAILS ********************
    public List<Cust> GetCust(int CustyID)
    {
        GlobalVar.connection();
        List<Cust> CustyChosen = new List<Cust>();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("psv_CustView1", GlobalVar.con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustyID", CustyID);

        SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        GlobalVar.con.Open();
        sd.Fill(dt);
        GlobalVar.con.Close();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            CustyChosen.Add(
                new Cust
                {
                    CustID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CustID"]),
                    CustName = Convert.ToString(dr["CustName"]),
                    CustNotes = Convert.ToString(dr["CustNotes"]),
                });
            GlobalVar.GlobCustName1 = Convert.ToString(dr["CustName"]); //This method uses 
Global Var to get data to pass to form.  Can pass anything that way.
        }

        return CustyChosen;
    }

    public int SaveCust(int CustyID, string CustyName)
    {
        GlobalVar.connection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("psu_CustSave1", GlobalVar.con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustyID", CustyID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustyName", CustyName);

        GlobalVar.con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        //DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //sd.Fill(dt);
        GlobalVar.con.Close();

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to parse here, but what strikes me as the main part of the problem you have noted is:

a) You methods on the controller are not all decorated with HttpPost attributes.

b) The action on the form that you render will be looking for a POST endpoint with a name that matches the get

That said, you're going to find it hard to get answers for how to make this work, given that this is very non-idiomatic asp.net MVC code.

I would strongly suggest working through a few tutorials, as web dev is considerably different to windows dev, with a different set of challenges.  Hopefully your experience will let you skim through that quickly.